# Creating a spacetime plot in R

Tags: r, plot, time, space

I am working on a project for which I would show the change in my variable over time per country. I have found the library Spacetime. On [this website](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v051i07), in the pdf paper, page 18, I found an example graph which I try to recreate on my own data.

[image]

Unfortunately I got an error and I can't figure out where I made a mistake. Does someone know what is going wrong? Many thanks in advance!

```
#Library used
library("spacetime")
library(sp)
library("maptools")
library("maps")

#Example data
data <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                   text="Year Country Variable
                   2000 Hungary 1
                   2001 Hungary 2
                   2002 Hungary 1
                   2003 Hungary 4")

#Try to recreate plots from the website: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v051i07

statepro.m<-map('worldHires', c('Hungary'), plot = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
IDss <- sapply(strsplit(statepro.m$names, ":"), function(x) x[1])
statess <- map2SpatialPolygons(statepro.m, IDs=IDss)
yrs<-2000:2003
time <- as.POSIXct(paste(yrs, "-01-01", sep = ""), tz = "GMT")
data.st <- STFDF(statess, time, data[order(data[1], data[2]),])
```

> Error: nrow(object@data) == length(object@sp) * nrow(object@time) is not TRUE

Comment: maybe marrangeGrob with a layout matrix

Comment: Your `time` vector does not correspond to the time range of your example data. Change `yrs <- 2000:2003` and it works. After that `stplot(data.st)` gives you the desired plot.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave, it is working now. One more follow op question: if I try stplot(data.st) I plot the different years but I actually want to plot the variable called "Variable". Do you know how I can achieve that, I tried: stplot(data.st[, , "Variable"], yrs) which gave me the error: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘stplot’ for signature ‘"xts"’

Comment: I have never worked with the spacetime package, so don't rely solely on my advice. But in this toy example it seems sufficient to change the order of columns in the data frame when creating the STFDF object: `data.st <- STFDF(statess, time, data[order(data[1], data[2]), c(3,2,1)])` That said, you might consider checking out the newer sf package (by the same package author) and its more intuitive, tidyverse-compatible approach.